# Declaration of Child method should be compatible to Parent Method

Tags: php, yii2

got this error on Yii2. I dont know what exactly the problem is. I just migrate my source code from Windows to Mac OS. I tried cloning my whole project still the error appears.

**Declaration of common\models\Product::getAttributes() should be compatible with yii\base\Model::getAttributes($names = NULL, $except = Array)**

These are the things i tried:

1. Clone the whole project to Mac OS. - error above exists.
2. Clone the whole project to another windows machine.-the project is running well.

I am using yii2 in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the error message, you overrided `yii\base\Model` `getAttributes()` method. `common\models\Product` is extended from `yii\db\ActiveRecord` and `ActiveRecord` is extended from `yii\base\Model`.

If you really want to override this method, list all parameters (see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getAttributes%28%29-detail)), it's easier to do with help of IDE. And by the way this is PHP feature and has nothing to do with OS or Yii2.

If it is your custom method for another purposes, you need to rename it in order to resolve conflict.

Comment: hello! thanks for you help. I am newbie in overriding methods and your explanation really helps.:) also, i add ($names = NULL, $except = Array) as added by visualex

Answer (score 0):

Your method must accept the same parameters  ($names = NULL, $except = Array)